# BeautifulSoup 4 - Scraping element (h2) outside of div

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape some football match data from the following site below:

https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php

Looking at the source code of the site I was able to identify that most of the information (team names, start time and channels) is contained within an outer div ( div class="blockfix"). I am able to scrape this data successfully using the code below:

```
import requests
import time
import csv
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def makesoup(url):
    page=requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
   
    
    
def matchscrape(g_data):
    
    for item in g_data:
        try:
            match = item.find_all("div", {"class": "fix"})[0].text
            print(match)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            starttime = item.find_all("div", {"class": "fLeft_time_live"})[0].text
            print(starttime)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            channel = item.find_all("td", {"class": "chan_col"})
            for i in channel:
                    print(i.get_text().strip())
        except:
            pass
            
            
            
def start():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php")
    matchscrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "blockfix"}))

    
        
        
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry("600x600")
root.wm_title("liveonsat scraper")
Label = tk.Label(root, text = 'liveonsat scraper', font = ('Comic Sans MS',18))
button = tk.Button(root, text="Scrape Matches", command=start)
button3 = tk.Button(root,  text = "Quit Program", command=quit)
Label.pack()
button.pack()
button3.pack()
status_label = tk.Label(text="")
status_label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I receive the following output for example :

[image: Output]

The issue I am having is that one element (date of the matches) is contained outside of the div ( div class="blockfix"). I am unsure as to how I am able to retrieve this data. I tried to change the following code below:

```
def start():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php")
    matchscrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "blockfix"}))
```

to

```
def start():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php")
    matchscrape(g_data = soup.findAll("td", {"height": "50"}))
```

as this element contained the h2 tag for date of the matches ( h2 class="time_head), but when I attempt this I get a completely different output which is incorrect (see code below)

```
def matchscrape(g_data):
    
    for item in g_data:
        try:
            match = item.find_all("div", {"class": "fix"})[0].text
            print(match)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            matchdate = item.find_all("h2", {"class": "time_head"})[0].text
            print(matchdate)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            starttime = item.find_all("div", {"class": "fLeft_time_live"})[0].text
            print(starttime)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            channel = item.find_all("td", {"class": "chan_col"})
            for i in channel:
                    print(i.get_text().strip())
        except:
            pass
            
            
            
def start():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php")
    matchscrape(g_data = soup.findAll("td", {"height": "50"}))
```

**Incorrect Output:** (due to only one match name, time and date being outputted with 100's of channel names)

[image: wrongoutput]

To further clarify. The end result I am trying to achieve is each match, time of each match, channels showing each match and date match is showing to be scraped and outputted (printed).

Thank you to anyone who can provide guidance or assistance to me with this issue. If further clarification or anything else is required I will be more than happy to provide.

Update: Below is HTML code as requested in the comments for one match as an example. The element I am having issue with displaying is h2 class="time_head"

```
<div style="clear:right">    <div class=floatAndClearL><h2 class = sport_head >Football</h2></div>  <!-- sport_head -->
    <div class=floatAndClearL><h2 class = time_head>Friday, 10th  July</h2></div> <!-- time_head -->         <div><span class = comp_head>English Championship - Week 43</span></div>
       <div class = blockfix >                <!-- block 1-->
    <div class=fix>                 <!-- around fixture and notes 2-->
          <div class=fix_text>               <!-- around fixture text 3-->
              <div class = imgCenter><span><img src="../img/team/england.gif"></span></div>
              <div class = fLeft style="width:270px;text-align:center;background-color:#ffd379;color:#800000;font-size:10pt;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif">Huddersfield v Luton Town</div>
              <div class = imgCenter><img src="../img/team/england.gif"></div>
    </div>                  <!-- around fixture text 3 ENDS-->
        <div class=notes></div>
     </div>                  <!-- around fixture and notes 2 ENDS-->
            <div class = fLeft>                <!-- around all of channel types 2-->     <div>             <!-- around channel type group 3-->
       <div class=fLeft_icon_live_l>       <!-- around icon 4-->
         <img src="../img/icon/live3.png"/>
       </div>
       <div class=fLeft_time_live>       <!-- around icon 4-->
         ST: 18:00
       </div>           <!-- around icon 4 ENDS-->        <div class = fLeft_live>       <!-- around all tables of a channel type 4-->       <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class=chan_col>  <a href="https://connect.bein.net/" target="_blank"  class = chan_live_iptvcable>              beIN Connect MENA </a></td><td width = 0></td>
                    </tr></table>       <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class=chan_col>  <a href="https://tr.beinsports.com/kullanici/giris?ReturnUrl=" target="_blank"  class = chan_live_iptvcable>              beIN Connect TURKEY </a></td><td width = 0></td>
                    </tr></table>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant element in the HTML source? As an aside, using `except: pass` is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Added the html to the original post as there was not enough space to add as a comment here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could achieve it:

```
import requests
import re
import unidecode
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get page source
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

response = requests.get('https://liveonsat.com/uk-england-all-football.php', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

# process results

for match in soup.find_all('div',class_='blockfix'):
    #Competitors list. Using Regex, we look for a div containing two competitors name sepatated by a ' v '
    competitors = match.find('div', text = re.compile(r'(.*) v (.*)')).text
    # Looking at the match date by searching the previous h2 tag with time_head as class attribute
    match_date  = match.find_previous('h2',class_='time_head').text
    fLeft_time_live = match.find('div',class_='fLeft_time_live').text.strip()
    #Match time
    channels = match.find('div',class_='fLeft_live')
    print("Competitors ", competitors)
    print("Match date", match_date)
    print("Match time", fLeft_time_live)
    
    #Grab tv transmission times
    for channel in channels.find_all('a'):
        # if the show time is available, it will be contained in a "mouseover" tag
        # we try to find this tag, otherwise we just display the channel name
        try:
            show_date = BeautifulSoup(channel.get('onmouseover')).text
        except:
            print("  " ,channel.text.strip().replace('ðŸ“º',''), "- no time displayed - ",)
            continue
        show_date  = unidecode.unidecode(show_date )
        #Some regex logic to extract the show date
        pattern = r"CAPTION, '(.*)'\)"
        show_date  = re.search(pattern,show_date ).group(1)
        print("  ", show_date )
        
    print()
```

**Output**

```
Competitors  Huddersfield v Luton Town
Match date Friday, 10th  July
Match time ST: 19:00
   beIN Connect MENA  - no time displayed - 
   beIN Connect TURKEY  - no time displayed - 
   beIN Sports MENA 12 HD  - 2020-07-10 17:00:00
   beIN Sports MENA 2 HD  - 2020-07-10 17:00:00
   beIN Sports Turkey 4 HD  - 2020-07-10 17:00:00
   Eleven Sports 2 Portugal HD  - 2020-07-10 17:00:00
   ....
```

**EDIT** : corrected the match date extraction ...

Comment: Thanks for this. One thing i have noticed though is in the output the match date for every match is showing as Friday 10th July even for matches thats date should be Satrday 11th and so on. Do you know what could cause this? Thanks

Comment: added a correction in the code, the idea is to look at the previous sibbling matching a certain condition (being a `h2` tag with the `time_head` class).